# MIN function on mixed numeric/alphabetic values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a table with student records that identify several aspects of their enrollment, including their id, year enrolled, term enrolled, student type, etc.

The formula below is in one column in the table and works perfectly to identify the student's minimum year(and minimum term in the minimum year) per their id and type combined.  But it only works perfectly when the term value is numeric.  Some of the terms are letter/number combinations such as "A1","A2","A3","J1","J2","J3","M1","M2","M3" and for these rows, the code returns a #VALUE! error.

[image: Record Snapshot with Error]

```
=MIN(IF(([id_num]=[@[id_num]])*([TYPE CONSOLIDATION]=[@[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]]),NUMBERVALUE([yr_cde])))&"("&MIN(IF(([id_num]=[@[id_num]])*([TYPE CONSOLIDATION]=[@[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]]),IF(NUMBERVALUE([yr_cde])=MIN(IF(([id_num]=[@[id_num]])*([TYPE CONSOLIDATION]=[@[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]]),NUMBERVALUE([yr_cde]))),NUMBERVALUE([trm_cde]))))&")"
```

With some research I have found an index/match formula: `=INDEX([trm_cde],MATCH(MIN(CODE([trm_cde])),CODE([trm_cde]),0))` that will return the minimum value of the term for all the records in the table, but after many attempts, I cannot figure out how to incorporate it in the formula i need to identify the minimum by the id, type, and minimum year criteria.

Comment: Why are you YELLING?

Comment: I apologize.  I don't see where I'm using all caps except where fields are labeled with all caps.  Those fields denoted with caps differentiate them from the imported fields from the database so it is easy to identify them as calculated fields :)

Comment: Your question title was in all caps, which [I've edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34160090/revisions) now.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize I had written it in all caps.

Comment: Which order are you looking at? having "10, J1, J2, M1, A1" what comes first? (is the min)

Comment: Number values such as 10, 20, 30 would come before mixed letter/number values and the letter/number values would be in the order of A1, A2, A3, F1, F2, F3, J1, J2, J3, M1, M2, M3, Z1, Z2, Z3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
=INDEX([yr_cde],MATCH(MIN(IF([@[id_num]]&[@[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]]=[id_num]&[TYPE CONSOLIDATION],[yr_cde])),[yr_cde],0))&"("&INDEX([trm_cde],MATCH(MIN(IF([@[id_num]]&[@[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]]=[id_num]&[TYPE CONSOLIDATION],[yr_cde])),[yr_cde],0))&")"
```

It is an array formula so it needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Just realized this will only work if table is sorted by if_num, yr_code, trm_cde.

---

Edit 2:

This formula will work regardless of sort order:

```
=INDEX([yr_cde],MATCH(MIN(IF([id_num]&[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]=[@[id_num]]&[@[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]],[yr_cde]*1000+(CODE([trm_cde])*10)+RIGHT([trm_cde],1))),[yr_cde]*1000+(CODE([trm_cde])*10)+RIGHT([trm_cde],1),0))&"("&INDEX([trm_cde],MATCH(MIN(IF([id_num]&[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]=[@[id_num]]&[@[TYPE CONSOLIDATION]],[yr_cde]*1000+(CODE([trm_cde])*10)+RIGHT([trm_cde],1))),[yr_cde]*1000+(CODE([trm_cde])*10)+RIGHT([trm_cde],1),0))&")"
```

It is an array formula so it needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: @LindsayPatterson Try new edit.  It should work regardless of sort.

Comment: Edit 2 worked perfectly.  I am working it out piece by piece to understand it (most of it makes sense), but it definitely worked for all 48K+ records. Thank you very much Scott :)  You're an Excel guru to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you may be misinterpreting the purpose of the [NUMBERVALUE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NUMBERVALUE-function-1B05C8CF-2BFA-4437-AF70-596C7EA7D879). Its intended use is to translate text-that-looks-like-a-number in a regional number format (e.g. **2.500,27**) to a raw numerical format that can be dealt with mathematically. It is not intended to try and interpret a strictly text value such as **J1** into a numerical value. This is the source of your [#VALUE!](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/correct-a-value-error-cec24732-88fc-4b76-945c-32fd4e847573) error on the **trm_cde** column. The use of NUMBERVALUE on the **yr_cde** column is unnecessary as no regional translation is necessary. It would be more efficient to simply have true numbers representing the years in the yr_cde column; the error notifications evident in your image together with the values' left alignment would seem to suggest that they are text masquerading as numbers.

In the following sample data, I've forced the **yr_cde** column into text values that look like numerical years (evident by their error notations and left alignment) and left the **trm_cde** column split between true numbers and true text.

In the first data row of the **earliest year/term per ID and type** column, (F3 in my sample image), use this array formula².

```
=IFERROR(
  LEFT(AGGREGATE(15, 7, IF(ISTEXT([trm_cde]), [yr_cde]&MID([trm_cde], 2, 9), [yr_cde]&[trm_cde])/(([id_num]=[@[id_num]])*([type consoldiation]=[@[type consoldiation]])), 1), 4)&
  " ("&IF(ISTEXT([@[trm_cde]]), LEFT([@[trm_cde]], 1), "")&
  MID(AGGREGATE(15, 7, IF(ISTEXT([trm_cde]), [yr_cde]&
  MID([trm_cde], 2, 9), [yr_cde]&[trm_cde])/(([id_num]=[@[id_num]])*([type consoldiation]=[@[type consoldiation]])), 1), 5, 9)
  &")", "")
```

I've used the [AGGREGATE³ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) to determine the [SMALL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29)est combined value. You should also be able to return the second or third lowest by adjusting the *k* parameter (see column G in the sample image). Check the linked documentation for other options.

[image: minimum_text_values]
                    <sup>Minimum value of text and number combinations</sup>

---

¹ <sub>The [NUMBERVALUE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NUMBERVALUE-function-1B05C8CF-2BFA-4437-AF70-596C7EA7D879) was introduced with Excel 2013. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

² <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>

³ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>

Comment: You're looking at the column I added with the 2nd earliest. The earliest is in column F.   :P

Comment: Ah I see it now, my bad.

Comment: The yr_cde and trm_cde columns are populated by a data connection which remains live and refreshed regularly via SQL.  In order to make the yr_cde and trm_cde fields numeric, I would need to use a code in the SQL which I'm not familiar with.  Changing the format in the worksheet only gets overridden when the sheet is refreshed which is why the columns remain as text.  I did however, very much appreciate your insight provided with your solution.  Thank you very much.

Comment: i really do like the way you incorporated the Aggregate function.  I have not used that one before and I am looking forward to trying it out with a future solution!

Comment: If that's a live feed from SQL then an SQL View could be set up with a calculated field that would make that oddball *Earliest Year (Type)* a piece of cake.

Comment: I'd definitely be open to an additional solution in SQL!  However, I doubt you much want to waste your time on it here in this question, since the solution was provided with an Excel formula.

Comment: The trick to constructing a View will be the subquery for catenation of a 'earliest_year_type' field but that isn't tough. Since this would be SQL specific, you're right, it belongs under a [sql] or [ms-sql] tag but you will find quick, focused responses there. Once you are tapping into the power of the SQL engine even a partition table is possible with a View. Excel will see it as simply SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_My_View or you can select fields as you see fit. I prefer the latter; better to have too many fields in a View than have to make a new View somewhere down the road for a field you missed.